# How to I navigate back to a previously loaded xib file?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiviewcontroller, xib

In my app, I have three views. Originally, the `appDelegate` opened the xib file for the `mainViewController`, and the preset settings on my application template included a `flipsideViewController`, which would be shown when an information button was hit.

Later I decided to include another view controller and xib file, called `CountySelectionViewController`. The xib file has a button that opens the xib file for the `mainViewController` via the following:

```m
MainViewController *controller = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil];
controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
```

Should I use the same thing to go back to the `CountySelectionViewController` as well as its xib? or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` -- http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: